# How to iterate over features and abort iteration with keypress in PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I would like to run a loop with PyQGIS, it should wait for the user to press a key either SpaceBar or Escape to continue.

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
aLayer = canvas.currentLayer()

feat = QgsFeature()
iter = aLayer.getFeatures()

while iter.nextFeature(feat):
    aLayer.removeSelection()
    aLayer.select(feat.id())
    qgis.utils.iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()

    <wait for user input>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This probably helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255463/exit-while-loop-by-user-hitting-enter-key

Comment: Do you want it to abort iteration or continue to the next feature? If you want it to abort, it will only zoom to the first feature.

Comment: I would like to continue to the next feature, until the user presses esc/spacebar...

Comment: I have not tried your code gcarrillo, will let you know soon...

Comment: Ok, let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 7):

**Note:** This answer was posted for QGIS 2. [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/376318/4972) you can find a QGIS 3 version.

---

If I got you right, you can follow this workflow to iterate through features by pressing the space bar:

1. Open QGIS, load your layer(s), and save your project.
2. Download the script [iterate_features.py](https://github.com/gacarrillor/pyqgis_scripts/blob/master/iterate_features.py) and save it in the same folder as your QGIS project.
3. Open the QGIS Python console (`Plugins->Python console`), type the following line, and then press Enter:

   ```
    import iterate_features
   ```
4. Now click anywhere on your map or ToC.

You should now be able to select and zoom in to the next feature by pressing the space bar or to finish the iteration by pressing Escape.

It should work on the active layer in the ToC, each time you change the active layer, the iterator is restarted.