# QGIS: Jump to next feature (like in Atlas)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I would like to jump to next feature in my attribute table. I know this is possible with the "print composer" using "atlas".

Is there any possibility to jump to the next feature in my attribute table using the standard QGIS canvas?

Comment: In [How to iterate over features and abort iteration with keypress in PyQGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133189/how-to-iterate-over-features-and-abort-iteration-with-keypress-in-pyqgis) you can find a way to jump to the next feature (select it and zoom to it in the map canvas) of the active layer by pressing the space bar. You can have a look at [the code](https://github.com/gacarrillor/pyqgis_scripts/blob/master/iterate_features.py) to adjust it to your needs. Let me know if you need more guidance.

Comment: It worked for me **yay** .
However, it would be cool to have a less hackerish method :-)

Comment: I don't know if it makes sense to write yet another plugin, but the selenext plugin's source code hurts my eyes, from the [README](https://github.com/geodrinx/selenext) itself. I don't feel like contributing to it in its current state.

Comment: BTW, what's your use case?

Comment: I have some GPS tracks. They are distributed over a large area. I want to view and modify each track. So need to jump from one feature to another. Before I used the attribute table. There I always had to right-click on each feature and select "zoom to feature". This is very laborious. Your solutions is much more convenient.

Answer (score 5):

The [selenext Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/selenext/) will do the trick.
It opens a new toolbar with up and down arrows that go through the features of the active layer

[image]

Comment: thx. Unfortunately "selenext" has problems with different CRS. My data is in EPSG:4326 but I display it in EPSG:3857. So "selenext" always jumps to "null island"

Comment: @coding_bird Ah, I see what you mean, I've checked it using the same CRS for the layer and the map.

Answer (score 1):

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/134572/52597 mostly answered my question.

However, I am still looking for an less hackerish method.