# Adding textbox to QGIS plugin toolbar?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I am trying to write a plugin with a input control such as textbox on it. I looked around quite a bit for building  plugins. But I can only find examples of how to build a plugin with buttons/icons in its toolbar.

*How can I add other widgets such as a textbox on my plugin's toolbar?*

For the button, there isn't much to handle except for a callback when it's clicked. I imagine it would be quite different for a textbox as one needs to associate the input control to e.g. a global variable??

For now, I need interaction with the textbox (`QLineEdit`). I want to implement a plugin for [going to the next feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133189/) where I can display the row number of the current record, and jump to any given row by entering its row number.

I am using QGIS2.99 and Qt5, the standard `Plugin Builder` and `pb_tool` to `create` and `deploy` the plugin template. I suppose I need to add the `QLineEdit` in `initGui()` of the main `py` file(as shown below). I don't know much about Qt5, and only figured I might need `addUserInputWidget()` and/or connect it with the `add_action()` function? But I don't know how to put the pieces together, and register the events etc.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def initGui(self):
    """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

    # Create & add a textbox
    self.textbox = QLineEdit(self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.textbox.resize(80,20)

    self.txtAction = self.toolbar.addWidget(self.textbox)
    #should I use addUserInputWidget(self.textbox) #??

    self.txtAction.setToolTip(self.tr(u'Current Row Number'))
    #callback=self.runTextChange   how to register an event handler?
```

The UI shows but there is no interaction.

Can someone help explain how to link the `QLineEdit` to the toolbar so that I can get/change the text value?

Also, a minor issue I can't figure out is that the textbox takes up the full width of the toolbar no matter what I use in its `.resize()` method. How should I limit its width?

Comment: Have a look at my answer. I'm not sure it can help you so, if you think it is very far from your needs or simply off-topic, please notify me it and I will delete the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice answer by [@mgri](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/87487/mgri) (*don't delete it as it is useful to use within QGIS!*). I tested the following on QGIS 2.18 also with Qt4 but perhaps it might be useful too as the other answer. A couple of things to note:

- You can use `self.textbox.setFixedWidth(80)` to set the width of the textbox.
- You can use `self.textbox.textChanged.connect(self.runTextChange)` to connect the textbox to a function whenever the text is changed.

Here is the code used:

```
def initGui(self):
    """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""
    # Create & add a textbox
    self.textbox = QLineEdit(self.iface.mainWindow())
    # Set width
    self.textbox.setFixedWidth(80)
    # Add textbox to toolbar
    self.txtAction = self.toolbar.addWidget(self.textbox)
    # Set tooltip
    self.txtAction.setToolTip(self.tr(u'Current Row Number'))
    # Set callback
    self.textbox.textChanged.connect(self.runTextChange)


def runTextChange(self, rownum):
    # Set active layer
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    # If textbox is empty or 0 then deselect all features
    if rownum == '' or int(rownum) == 0:
        layer.deselect([feat.id() for feat in layer.getFeatures()])
    else:
        # Else select row number matching the entered value
        for feat in layer.getFeatures():
            if feat.id() == int(rownum) - 1:
                layer.setSelectedFeatures([feat.id()])
```

---

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Quite different from my answer, but I'm sure this will solve the issue :)

Comment: @mgri - Haven't used QGIS 2.99 or Qt5 so who knows :) Although I am dreading how much changes I will need to make to my plugins when QGIS 3 is officially released >_<

Comment: I know, it will be a common nightmare for all of us (and probably for the whole community since there will be a lot of answers with deprecated APIs).

Comment: Thanks! I only needed to change the last line to `layer.selectByIds(...` to make it work..

Answer (score 5):

This would be more a comment than an answer (and most probably a starting point rather than a solution), but I post it here since there is some code.

If you want to set up a basic textbox, you may use this code:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

input_dialog = QInputDialog()
title = "Dialog Title"
label = "Enter some text here: "
enum_type = QLineEdit.Normal
default_text = "<your text here>"

res = QInputDialog.getText(input_dialog, title, label, enum_type, default_text)
```

The `res` variable is a tuple that stores your text (as a string) and a boolean which is used to verify that an input was typed. You can also change the last line in:

```
text_var, typed = QInputDialog.getText(input_dialog, title, label, enum_type, default_text)
```

for directly having your text stored in the `text_var` variable.

**Note** that this works for Qt4, but I think it should follow the same syntax also for Qt5.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help. But I am looking for a more direct connection between the lineedit and the python code/global variable so that they notify each other of value changes and act accordingly.

Comment: @tinlyx You confirmed my doubts about the usefulness of my tip. Sorry, but these operations are not *my cup of tea*... Good luck! :)