# Combining a MapTool and a QGIS plugin toolbar?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

This is a follow-up question to my question about how to build a QGIS plugin and link a textbox to the plugin toolbar ([Adding textbox to QGIS plugin toolbar?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244584/)).

In addition to that, I was wondering how to add functions of a Map Tool in order to start a different "mode". By mode, I mean something like a editor mode or the identify tool, where the meaning of mouse clicks, scroll event etc change to fit the current task at hand.

I found an answer to this GIS.SE question ([Programatically check for mouse click in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45094/)), and tested its functions. It seems to be a good start and can handle a mouse click event, when activated with

```
tool = PointTool(qgis.iface.mapCanvas())
qgis.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)
```

My questions are:

Both the `PointTool(QgsMapTool)` and plugin created with QGIS's standard Plugin Builder (and `pb_tool`) can handle various events. Which events should be handled by the MapTool vs by the Plugin? Is there a convention on this?

Also, how to link the MapTool to the Plugin (or embed the MapTool in the Plugin)? Is there a conventional way?

For example, if I click any button in the plugin toolbar, the mouse icon should change to a different shape. Currently, the mouse is still a magnifying class after I activate the MapTool.

How to properly register the tool when the plugin is activated and restore to the previous tool/mode when, e.g., the plugin toolbar is closed/hidden?

Answer (score 3):

You can use virtual `QAction` from `QgsInterface` Class. There is for example, `actionIdentify()` that you can trigger when the user click on your button. It will start the Identify Tool.

For example you can define a function like that (you can add the code you need for your task, like set the layer to work with, selecting features,...):

```
def myIdentifyTool():
    self.iface.actionIdentify().trigger()
```

and connect your button to this function like that:

```
self.widget.your_button.clicked.connect(self.myIdentifyTool)
```

So when you click your button, the Identify tool will be trigger.

Have a look to the [`QgsInterface` class documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html) to see all QAction available.